# CSS have each grid element a different height

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-grid

I have a grid with three columns and the height changes to fit all the text.

```
.main .contentWrapper {
    height:60%;
    margin-top:5%;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap:10px;
    /*grid-template-rows: auto;*/
    height:auto;
}

.main .contentWrapper .box .boxText {
    padding:15px;
    height:25%;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0;
}

img {
    object-fit:cover;
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
    margin:0;
}
```

How can I make it so each box resizes to fit its own text, and they're not all the same height? As it is the first two columns resize to fit the largest piece of text which is in the third column.

[image: box layout]

Comment: Please show us your HTML

Comment: did you try min-height or height auto?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The default value of property `align-items` for a *grid container* is `stretch` which means each *grid item* will extend to the height of the *grid row* (to the largest item in the row if height is not set using `grid-template-rows`).

To change this you can just add `align-items: flex-start` to the *grid container* (`.contentWrapper`) - see demo below:

```css
body {
  background: #ddd;
}

.contentWrapper {
  height: 60%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  /*grid-template-rows: auto;*/
  height: auto;
  align-items: flex-start; /* ADDED */
}

.contentWrapper .box .boxText {
  padding: 15px;
  height: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  background: #fff;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="contentWrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
    <div class="boxText">Some text here</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
    <div class="boxText">Some text here Some text here Some text here </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
    <div class="boxText">Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text
      here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this was to add `margin-bottom: auto` to each `.contentWrapper .box`. This pushed the text flush to the image and fit each cell to its content.

[image]

```css
.main .contentWrapper {
  height: 60%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  /*grid-template-rows: auto;*/
  height: auto;
}

.main .contentWrapper .box {
  background-color: #eee;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.main .contentWrapper .box .boxText {
  padding: 15px;
  height: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="contentWrapper">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="">
      <div class="boxText">text text text text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="">
      <div class="boxText">text text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="">
      <div class="boxText">text text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bzcdk6ts/2/)